# Database for big records

Tags: database, nosql

What is the best database for storing big chunks of data? I want to store the following stucture:

| batch_id (int, key) | part_number (int, key) | chunk (blob, around 5MB) |

There might be thousands of that records. I thought about some NoSQL solutions. Maybe MongoDB? It's also nice to have nicely supported Java connection driver for this database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you store blobs as files in the file system, and store paths in the database.